# ItextSharp text operations

Tags: c#

```
table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Sample text", font));
```

How can I set this text to center of the cell and add background of cell?

Comment: What element is "table"?

Comment: `PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code for it:

```
    PdfPCell c;
    c = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(@"Sample text", font));
    c.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    c.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    c.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK;
    table.AddCell(c);
```

Hope this will work..